Why did I get downvoted?
I got downvoted for this question. Is there anything wrong with this question? If so, please let me know and I will take it down. It's bad enough that I am not getting any answers or sensible feedback. People seem to enjoy downvoting me without mentioning reasons for it.

I think your question is valid. StackExchange is an inherently democratic site so a single downvote is nothing to be concerned about. Certainly feeling the need to remove a question because it has one down vote is an overreaction. There is no stipulatated requirement to state a reason for a downvote or an upvote.
I dont know the answer to your question off hand or without doing a reasonable amount of work but I suspect that it might attract downvotes is because either:
a) it can be answered by performing some fairly basic data analysis and looking at timeseries yourself.
b) it might be missing information or may be too vague (this is purely speculative on my part and this is my instinct here).
Also the question has been alive only for 3 hours. Saying that its "bad enough" you are not getting answers or feedback is not appropriate at this stage. Usually questions on this forum can take days, if not weeks, to be answered properly.
I don't know if you have posted the question multiple times to bump it, in which case that is also a strong reasons questions get downvotes. But I haven't seen your question before so I will assume not.

Thanks for your kind message. I realized I had made a mistake in asking my question. So I have corrected it. I hope someone will answer it for me.
